# Dynamically replace ng-bind with ng-bind-html

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to replace the `ng-bind` attributes with `ng-bind-html` for certain tags dynamically, e.g with the sample code below I want to do it for all elements with the `.text` class.

```
<div class="text">{{text}}</div>
<div>{{text1}}</div>
<p class="text">{{text}}</p>
```

I am trying to do with the following jquery code and its not working, any pointers would be much appreciated.

$('.text').attr('ng-bind-html', 'text').removeAttr('ng-bind')

Comment: `ng-bind-html` "includes" `ng-bind` capabilities, so you can always use it.

Answer (score 0):

did you mean that

```
$('.text').removeAttr('ng-bind').attr('ng-bind-html', 'text');
```

Answer (score 0):

Directly use **ng-bind-html** for both the cases, it will work.
because, ng-bind-html has ng-bind inside in it.